# Why can we assume a triangulated graph without loss of generality, for proofs of the 4 colour theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, coloring, planar-graphs

In [the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) about the four colour theorem it is stated

> First, if planar regions separated by the graph are not triangulated, i.e. do not have exactly three edges in their boundaries, we can add edges without introducing new vertices in order to make every region triangular, including the unbounded outer region. If this triangulated graph is colorable using four colors or fewer, so is the original graph since the same coloring is valid if edges are removed.

How is the same coloring valid if we remove edges? This will make a union of regions with different colours and neighboring several other regions. How can we choose the same coloring and if there is some process to do so, how will it be valid?

Comment: They are coloring the vertices not the edges. So an added edge would impose more conditions, which with the edge removed is OK since adjacent vertices are still adjacent in the triangulated graph.

Comment: So it refers to the graph representation of the regions? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#/media/File%3AFour_Colour_Planar_Graph.svg

Comment: In above they are not covering the regions or edges. Each country is represented by a vertex, and two vertices are connected by an edge iff the corresponding countries border along a common edge. [yes to your last comment referring to the wiki link]